# Sending data using POST in Python to PHP. I have any result in the PHP SCRIPT

Tags: php, python-3.x, python-2.7, apache, httprequest

I recently found a solution to communicate between python and php script with this example :

**python client :**

```
import requests
userdata = {"firstname": "Smith", "lastname": "Ayasaki", "password": "123456"}
resp = requests.post('http://localhost/api.php', data = userdata)
```

**api.php script :**

```
<?php
    $firstname = htmlspecialchars($_POST["firstname"]);
    $lastname = htmlspecialchars($_POST["lastname"]);
    $password = htmlspecialchars($_POST["password"]);
    echo "FIRSTNAME: $firstname  LASTNAME: $lastname  PW: $password";
  ?>
```

But it's not work at all, I use apache2 port:80 and i'm working in localhhost, so maybe it's normal that doesn't work because the python client send to the api.php but I can't see the result ...
So the solution I found is to send the `$firstname,$lastname,$password` in a database, to check if really information are sending , there is new api.php :

```
<?php
try
    {
      $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=api;charset=utf8', 'root', '');
    }
   catch(Exception $e)
   {
     die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());
   }



      $firstname = htmlspecialchars($_POST["firstname"]);
      $lastname = htmlspecialchars($_POST["lastname"]);
      $password = htmlspecialchars($_POST["password"]);


      $req = $bdd->prepare( '                            
                              INSERT INTO reception(nom,prenom,identifiant)
                               VALUES (:lastname,:firstname,:password);
                            ' );


    $req->execute(array('lastname' => $lastname, 'firstname' => $firstname,'password' => $password)); 
    ?>
```

Please help to resolve this, I'm not expert in http request ! and sorry for my english ...

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good. I tested it here and it works (the new version).
To debug your code, you can see whats getting posted by adding the following line in your python script (at the end):

```
print(resp.text)
```

It will post the response from your webserver.

And check if the following details are correct:

```
database: api
username: root
password: <<empty>>
table:    reception
fields:   nom
          prenom
          identifiant
```

And also check what the response is from your webserver if you go to: `http://localhost/api.php` maybe it gives you some errors.

Comment: thanks for your  answer, i trie the print(resp.text) and i have this result : <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>401 Unauthorized</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Unauthorized</h1>
<p>This server could not verify that you
are authorized to access the document
requested.  Either you supplied the wrong
credentials (e.g., bad password), or your
browser doesn't understand how to supply
the credentials required.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.23 (Win64) PHP/5.6.25 Server at localhost Port 80</address>
</body></html>

Comment: apache problem ?

Comment: What do you see when you surf to http://localhost/api.php ? And does the file exists? And do you need an username and password?

Comment: yes the file exists but there is error of _$POST :                                       Notice: Undefined index: firstname in C:\wamp\www\api.php on line 13 Notice: Undefined index: lastname in C:\wamp\www\api.php on line 14    Notice: Undefined index: password in C:\wamp\www\api.php on line 15  for data base i can acces just with root and password, i deleted it in the description but he exist , the problem is in POST REQUEST MAYBE

Comment: That is correct, because there is no 'post'. Are you sure it is http and not https?

Comment: ooooo !! that's working ! you were right, it was the htaccess file that I put in the folder www / which block the connection